# Firebase Function Error: The default Firebase app does not exist

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Previously, the function worked. but I added some code, now this error is coming. How to fix this issue?

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/demo/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
```

**code**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { getLocations, getLocationsByType } from '../service/locationQuery/locationQuery';

//I tried both way, but same error came
// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.initializeApp();
exports.findUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
```

Comment: why someone votes down my question? what is the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I changed initialize place.. now It's working. I have no idea why is that.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();//add to here
import { getLocations, getLocationsByType } from '../service/locationQuery/locationQuery';

// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.findUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
```

Comment: It seems that you must have `admin.initializeApp()` before any functions are imported/exported in the index file. This is demonstrated in @Denis Alarie 4RP answer.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the place where you initialize your app might be important in ensuring that any declarations that require the app to be initialized come after. I had the same problem and when I made this change in order  the problem went away..

THIS (succeeds)

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();//add to here
import { getLocations, getLocationsByType } from
```

is not the same as

THIS (fails)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { getLocations, getLocationsByType } from 
admin.initializeApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say where exactly is your problem (and I am not 100% sure the following will solve it), but there is a mismatch between the way you import the required modules:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import ...
//.....
```

and the way you export the Cloud Function:

```
exports.findUsers = functions.https.onCall(...)
```

As you will read [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/typescript-getting-started#what-is-different-about-typescript-in-this-example), the import corresponds to a TypeScript Cloud Function, while the export corresponds to a JavaScript one.

---

You should align your code to the correct mode (JS or TS) depending on what  you use (probably TS, since `data` and `context` are typed):

**JavaScript:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.findUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {...]);
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const findUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have modules files and have tried putting `admin.initializeApp();` to no avail, then it's may be the file structure or mismatched imports

Check `/functions/lib` for updates after build, and if there is more than 1 `functions/lib/**.js.map` being generated

Check to see if you have both `import admin = require('firebase-admin')` and `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`

1. `delete` lib directory
2. Move your `.ts .js` script files from `/functions/src/**` and `/functions/**` to `/functions/src/{folder}/**`  directory
3. Covert all `const admin = require('firebase-admin');` to `import admin = require('firebase-admin')`
4. Rebuild & update the `package.json` `main` if need necessary
5. `firebase serve` to test locally